# Can NotificationCenter post cross targets in Swift?

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, uikit

I'm trying to post a notification from keyboard class to main app, and update UI or suspend some feature wile the custom keyboard is on.

In keyboard's `viewDidLoad`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(Global.KeyboardNotification)))
```

RootViewController of the app

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardStatusChange(_:)), name: Notification.Name.init(rawValue: Global.KeyboardNotification), object: nil)
```

The implementation:

```
@objc func keyboardStatusChange(_ notification: Notification) {NSLog(TAG, "\(#function)")}
```

The function never been called, however these native api are working well:

`UIApplication.keyboardDidShowNotification`
`UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification`

I'm not sure why the notification not been called, but native can, is Apple doesn't allow notification cross or other things that I may missed?

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code, hopefully it will solve your problem

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the ```UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification``` and  ```UIApplication.keyboardDidShowNotification``` would be called in every type of keyboards, and any kinds of input view, ie: UIPickerView.

I need to know is my custom keyboard show up or not, I've set a global boolean variable in  custom keyboard's viewDidLoad, the value should be set to true if my keyboard is up, and set to false when viewWillDisappear.